# Giving conditions in model for values in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to give conditions to my fields in model so that when i define a value from my controller new action it automatically changes the value of another field.

For example

i have a migration as follows

```
class CreateTickets < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :tickets do |t|
      t.integer :card_no
      t.integer :token_num
      t.string :name
      t.integer:token_left 

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then when i assign values to the table i want to change the value of the token_left by itself.

condition would be:

```
token_left = 50 - Ticket.count
```

Ticket is my model class and my model is empty now but how to give conditions like this so that whenever i create a new data than token_left value changes by itself.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `before_create` callback in your model:

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :update_token_left

  # scopes, associations, methods, etc..

  private
  def update_token_left
    self.token_left = 50 - Ticket.count
  end
end
```

Comment: you mean `before_create`?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Doh, yes. Thanks!